# How to use SDL2's timer functions to increase a variable by 1 every xxx ms

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Using SDL2's time functions, this is what I want to happen inside my main loop:

```
if (angle < 360)
{
    ...every 300ms angle++ <-----how to use SDL's time functions to do this ?
}
else
{
    angle = 0;
}
```

I'll be using this angle variable as an arguement for SDL_RenderCopyEx to render a rotating texture...

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out, here is what I did if anybody is ever interested...

```
//declare outside main
int lastTime = 0, currentTime;

//within main: 
if (angle < 360)
{
    currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
    if(currentTime > lastTime + 100) //ms to wait before change angle
    {
        angle += 10; //angle = angle + 10
        lastTime = currentTime;
    }
}
else
{
    angle = 0; 
}

SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer,BGtexture, NULL, NULL,angle,NULL,SDL_FLIP_NONE)
```